# How to send string message via Bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I'am trying to send simple string message via bluetooth to another device. My code looks like this:

```
private ICollection<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;

private void SendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BluetoothDevice bd = null;
        foreach(var o in PairedListView.pairedDevices)
        {
            if(o.Selected == true)
            {
                bd = getPairedDevice(o.DeviceAddress);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(bd != null)
        {
            UUID uuid = UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            BluetoothSocket socket = bd.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            socket.Connect();
            Stream stream = socket.OutputStream;
            byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Testing message!");
            stream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            socket.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Alerts.showAlertMessage("Choose device", this);
        }
    }

private BluetoothDevice getPairedDevice(string address)
    {
        BluetoothDevice bd = null;
        foreach(var o in devicesArray)
        {
            if(o.Address == address)
            {
                bd = o;
                break;
            }
        }
        return bd;
    }
```

I'am expecting receive string message on choosen device. The problem is I'am getting error

```
Java.IO.IOException: Service discovery failed
```

When trying to connect. Could You tell me what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might try socket.getOutputStream() to receive the associated OutputStream. Check with socket.isConnected() the current state.

But look at the official Google example (bluetooth chat):  http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: Thanks for example, I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old example but to anyone looking for a solution to this exact problem , the problem is u call the socket.close() before starting the connection so all u need to do is to remove socket.close() any everything should work just fine